# Laravel old SQL to a Laravel Eloquent query

Tags: laravel, eloquent

is there a way, to get from this SQL:

```
SELECT *,

  (SELECT count(*)
   FROM addresssurveys
   WHERE savedtimestamp::date = sendout_date) AS y
FROM
  (SELECT created_at::date AS sendout_date,
          created_at::date AS x
   FROM addresssurveys
   GROUP BY created_at::date) AS main
```

an Eloquent statement?
I created already the sub from query:

```php
 $sub = Survey::select(DB::raw('created_at::date, created_at::date as sendout_date, created_at::date as x'))->groupBy(DB::raw('created_at::date'))->orderby('created_at')->get();
```

But how can I combine both?

Thanks

Comment: This online query builder by GitHub would definitely help you:
 https://sql2builder.github.io/

Comment: Put yout query in DB::select()

Comment: @sssurii I tried, I get this error `Parse error on line 3: Unexpected 'SELECT'`

Comment: I guess your current raw SQL query is incorrect, if it is working?

Comment: It would better, if you explain your requirement you want to achieve, may be it can be done with more simpler query.